# Работа со строками в очереди

Tags: c++, char

Мне нужно записать в очередь символы и вывести его кодом +1 , то есть в вели a получим b. У меня проблема с char , вместо символа выводит числа.

```
struct Node //описание узла списка{
unsigned char data;  //информационное поле
Node* next; //указатель на следующий элемент};

void Creation(Queue* Q) //создание очереди{
Q->first = new Node;
Q->first->next = NULL;
Q->last = Q->first;
Q->size = 0;}
bool Full(Queue* Q) //проверка очереди на пустоту{
if (Q->first == Q->last) return true;
else return false;}
int Top(Queue* Q) //вывод начального элемента{
return Q->first->next->data;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `char`, а не `int`.

Вы, видимо, выводите типа `cout << Top(Q);`, а `Top()` возвращает `int` - что просите, то и выводит...

Comment: Спасибо , очень помогли , не заметил сразу

Comment: Если помогло - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ (птичка слева от ответа).